# Tensor flow affecting multiprocessing/threading

Tags: python, tensorflow, jpeg, conv-neural-network

I have an image classifier that is attempting to classify images into three categories. I trained my model using the open-source TensorFlow for poets: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/#4

I have a list of about 350,000 images that I want to classify and I'm using multiprocess with threading to download a batch of images locally, classify them, and then purge the image directory.

**Multi-processing/threading:**

```
def download_image(photo_url):
    ext = photo_url.split('.')[-1]
    if ext in extensions:
        image_data = requests.get(photo_url, timeout=5).content
        photo_name = '{}.{}'.format(os.urandom(12).encode('hex'), ext)
        photo_dest = os.path.join(tmp_images_dir, photo_name)
        with open(photo_dest, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(image_data)

def thread_handler(image_list):
    jobs = []
    for image in image_list.split(','):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=download_image, args=(image,))
        jobs.append(thread)
        thread.start()
    for j in jobs:
        j.join()


def multi_download_images(image_list):
    pool = Pool(processes=cpu_count() - 1)
    print 'downloading images...'
    pool.map(thread_handler,image_list)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

**Image Classification:**

```
def classify_image_batch():
    print 'labeling images...'
    image_list = [f for f in os.listdir(tmp_images_dir)]
    with tf.gfile.FastGFile(graph_dir, 'rb') as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
        _ = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')
        results = []
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')
        bar = ProgressBar()
        for image in bar(image_list):
            try:
                image_path = os.path.join(tmp_images_dir, image)
                image_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile(image_path, 'rb').read()
                predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor,
                                       {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data})
                top_k = predictions[0].argsort()[-len(predictions[0]):][::-1]
                category = label_lines[top_k[0]]
                results.append((image, category))
            except:
                results.append((image, 'failed'))
    update_mongo_with_classification(results)
    sess.close()
```

**Loop**

```
def loop_image_classification():
    if tf.gfile.Exists(tmp_images_dir):
        tf.gfile.DeleteRecursively(tmp_images_dir)
    tf.gfile.MakeDirs(tmp_images_dir)

    multi_download_images()
    classify_image_batch()
    gc.collect()
```

I loop this download, classify, purge with a gc.collect() statement at the end to clean anything up.

This works smoothly for the first few iterations but then I notice that my machine stops using all of it's cores and relies on a single core to download and classify-- resulting in 1/16 of the normal performance. My gut instinct is that there is leakage from the TensorFlow as I am closing and joining my threads and pools. TensorFlow employs all of my cores during the first few speedy classification loops.

I have read about the graph_def growing too large/ adding nodes to my graph for each jpeg read in. But truth be told, the happenings under-the-hood of TensorFlow are still a mystery to me. I'd appreciate any direction that would help me with this problem/ make me better at TensorFlow.

Thanks!

Comment: Some people had memory growth with default malloc even when the graph was not growing, can you try sudo apt-get install google-perftools;
export LD_PRELOAD="/usr/lib/libtcmalloc.so.4"

Comment: couple of ways to make it faster 1) instead of batch size 1, use large batch size (the larger the better) 2) use TF input pipeline to read things instead of FastGFile (this will enable reading files in parallel with classification)

Comment: I would also think about keeping the created graphdef and session around between calls. Loading a graphdef and creating a session are fairly heavyweight operations, and it can't hurt to do them as little as possible.